# Vue.js export / import vuex module failing

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am trying to use a Vuex module , but it's not running fine , I get uknown action trying to dispatch it ...

**store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import * as getters from '@/store/getters'
import { state, actions, mutations } from '@/store/root'
import authentication from '@/store/modules/authentication'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters,
  modules: {
    authentication
  }
})

export default store
```

**store/modules/authentication.js**

```
import * as types from '@/store/mutation_types'
import firebase from 'firebase'

const authentication = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || null,
    account: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('account')) || null
  },
  actions: {
    signUserUp ({commit}, payload) {
     ...
    },
    signUserIn ({commit}, payload) {
     ...
    },
    setUser ({commit}, newUser) {
      console.log('STORE ACTION setUser: ', newUser)
      commit(types.SET_USER, newUser)
    },
    setAccount ({commit}, newAccount) {
     ...
    },
    logout: context => {
     ...
  },
  mutations: {
   ...
  }
}

export default authentication
```

**main.js**

```
store.dispatch('setUser', null) // <==  [vuex] unknown action type: setUser
```

what's wrong with my module declaration ?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `namespaced` module, you should include namespace in action name:

`store.dispatch('authentication/setUser', {});`

**More**

If you want to dispatch action from another namespaced module, you might want to use `{root: true}` paramter:

`dispatch('authentication/users', {}, { root: true });`